# jquery apply custom icons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, icons, accordion

My application is an old one and did not use the jQuery well. But I used jQuery Accordion in one of my pages.

I can not include all the style which has written in "jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css". So I have to customize it, so that it only contain the style needed to set the appearance of Accordion. What line of contents should not I remove ?

jQuery code:

```
var icons = {
            header: "ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
            headerSelected: "ui-icon ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
        };

        // Accordion for Router Configuration and UNC Image Reopsitory
        $("#dvAccordion").accordion(
        { autoHeight: false,
            collapsible: true,
            icons: icons
        }
    );
```

Contents on my css file

```
    .ui-accordion { width: 100%; }
/*border-color:#adb0b3; */
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header {border-color:#adb0b3; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;  margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; cursor: pointer; position: relative; margin-top: 1px; zoom: 1; background-color: #535353; color:White;}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-li-fix { display: inline;   }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active { border-bottom: 0 !important; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a { text-decoration:none;   font-family:Verdana,Tahoma,Arial; font-style:inherit; display: block; font-size: 1em; padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em; color:White;}
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a { padding-left: 2.2em; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon { position: absolute; left: .5em; top: 50%; margin-top: -8px; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content { padding: 1em 2.2em; border-top: 0; margin-top: -2px; position: relative; top: 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; overflow: auto; display: none; zoom: 1; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active { display: block; }

/* states and images */
.ui-icon { width: 16px; height: 16px; background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); }
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon {background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); }
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon {background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-default .ui-icon { background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon {background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-active .ui-icon {background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon {background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_228ef1_256x240.png); }
.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon {background-image: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_ffd27a_256x240.png); }

/*set icons for Accordion*/
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e { background-position: -112px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s { background-position: -128px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-w { background-position: -144px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-n { background-position: -160px -192px; }
```

And placed jQuery images on *Icons/jquery/*. **It forms a perfect Accodion, but I could not set the icons. Why ?**

Answer (score 3):

You have to put this MINIMUM CSS for your accordion & icons to work

```
/* Layout helpers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-helper-hidden
{
    display: none;
}
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible
{
    position: absolute !important;
    clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
    clip: rect(1px,1px,1px,1px);
}
.ui-helper-reset
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    line-height: 1.3;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 100%;
    list-style: none;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix
{
    display: inline-block;
}
/* required comment for clearfix to work in Opera \*/
* html .ui-helper-clearfix
{
    height: 1%;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix
{
    display: block;
}
/* end clearfix */
.ui-helper-zfix
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=0);
}


/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-disabled
{
    cursor: default !important;
}


/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */
.ui-icon
{
    display: block;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


/* Misc visuals
----------------------------------*/

/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}


/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget
{
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}
.ui-widget .ui-widget
{
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button
{
    font-family: Trebuchet MS, Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget-content
{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    background: #eeeeee url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_eeeeee_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x;
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget-content a
{
    color: #333333;
}
.ui-widget-header
{
    border: 1px solid #e78f08;
    background: #f6a828 url(images/ui-bg_gloss-wave_35_f6a828_500x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-widget-header a
{
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default
{
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    background: #f6f6f6 url(images/ui-bg_glass_100_f6f6f6_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #1c94c4;
}
.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited
{
    color: #1c94c4;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus
{
    border: 1px solid #fbcb09;
    background: #fdf5ce url(images/ui-bg_glass_100_fdf5ce_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #c77405;
}
.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover
{
    color: #c77405;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active
{
    border: 1px solid #fbd850;
    background: #ffffff url(images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #eb8f00;
}
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited
{
    color: #eb8f00;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.ui-widget :active
{
    outline: none;
}

/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight
{
    border: 1px solid #fed22f;
    background: #ffe45c url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_75_ffe45c_1x100.png) 50% top repeat-x;
    color: #363636;
}
.ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight a
{
    color: #363636;
}
.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error
{
    border: 1px solid #cd0a0a;
    background: #b81900 url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_18_b81900_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error a, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error a
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error-text, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error-text
{
    color: #ffffff;
}
.ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-primary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-primary
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-content .ui-priority-secondary, .ui-widget-header .ui-priority-secondary
{
    opacity: .7;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=70);
    font-weight: normal;
}
.ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-disabled, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-disabled
{
    opacity: .35;
    filter: Alpha(Opacity=35);
    background-image: none;
}

/* Icons
----------------------------------*/

/* states and images */
.ui-icon
{
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
.ui-widget-content .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png);
}
.ui-widget-header .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffffff_256x240.png);
}
.
 .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-hover .ui-icon, .ui-state-focus .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-active .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ef8c08_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-highlight .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_228ef1_256x240.png);
}
.ui-state-error .ui-icon, .ui-state-error-text .ui-icon
{
    background-image: url(images/ui-icons_ffd27a_256x240.png);
}

/* positioning */
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-e { background-position: -112px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-s { background-position: -128px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-w { background-position: -144px -192px; }
.ui-icon-circle-arrow-n { background-position: -160px -192px; }

/* Misc visuals
----------------------------------*/

/* Corner radius */
.ui-corner-tl { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-tr { -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-bl { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-br { -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-top { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-bottom { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-right {  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px; -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-left { -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px; -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; }
.ui-corner-all { -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; }

/* Overlays */
.ui-widget-overlay { background: #666666 url(images/ui-bg_diagonals-thick_20_666666_40x40.png) 50% 50% repeat; opacity: .50;filter:Alpha(Opacity=50); }
.ui-widget-shadow { margin: -5px 0 0 -5px; padding: 5px; background: #000000 url(images/ui-bg_flat_10_000000_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x; opacity: .20;filter:Alpha(Opacity=20); -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }/*


/* IE/Win - Fix animation bug - #4615 */
.ui-accordion
{
    width: 100%;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header
{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1px;
    zoom: 1;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-li-fix
{
    display: inline;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active
{
    border-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a
{
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
}
.ui-accordion-icons .ui-accordion-header a
{
    padding-left: 2.2em;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon
{
    position: absolute;
    left: .5em;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content
{
    padding: 1em 2.2em;
    border-top: 0;
    margin-top: -2px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: none;
    zoom: 1;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: - Thanks for your answer. You are a genius. Where are you from?

Comment: url(Icons/jquery/ui-icons_222222_256x240.png); I missed a slash(/) before Icons